# Setting default values of Mat-Select when options are retrieved from API

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

**What I expect**
Creating an angular material form with multiple options. When you first come to the page. There is a call to an api to load data to the form. So the form should have values already defaulted values. 
**Whats happening**
I can't seem to figure out why I can't load a defaulted option for the mat-options.

I can if its not coming from an api "shrugs" :|

I have a link to a [stalkblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/apkveaegrob?embed=1&file=app/select-overview-example.html) and some code below

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" class="col-12">
 <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center align-items-baseline">
   <mat-form-field class="col-auto">
     <mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn" formControlName="favoriteFood" placeholder="Favorite food">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods$ | async" [value]="food">
         {{food.viewValue}}
       </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>

   <p class="col-auto selected-food"> Selected value: {{formGroup.get('favoriteFood').value | json}} </p>
 </div>

</form>
```

.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs';



export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})

export class SelectOverviewExample implements OnInit {
    formGroup:FormGroup;
  foods$:Observable<Food[]>;
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder) { }


    ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      favoriteFood:[this.foods[0].viewValue,[Validators.required]]
    });
    this.foods$ = of(this.foods);

        this.formGroup.get('favoriteFood').patchValue(this.foods[0].viewValue);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need to use `compareWith` since `mat-select` supports objects for values without the need for `ngValue` or `compareWith`.

```html
<mat-select formControlName="favoriteFood" placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods$ | async" [value]="food">
        {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Secondly, you are setting your value to an object so you need to set your initial value as well to the entire object and not just `viewValue`. I'm assuming you used `patchValue` for testing purposes. It not required at all.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        favoriteFood: [this.foods[0], [Validators.required]]
    });

    this.foods$ = of(this.foods);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you.

HTML.

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<h4>Basic native select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
  <select matNativeControl required>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</mat-form-field>

<h4>Usuarios</h4>
<mat-form-field class="col-auto">
  <mat-label>Usuarios</mat-label>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="changeClient($event.value)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of usuarios$  | async" [value]="user.id"> 
      {{user.title}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

export interface Usuarios {
  body: string
  id: number
  title:string
  userId: number
}

@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})

export class SelectOverviewExample implements OnInit {

  formGroup:FormGroup;
  foods$:Observable<Food[]>;
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];


  usuarios$:Observable<Usuarios[]>;
  selected = '';

  httpOptions = { 
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    })
  };

  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder, private _http: HttpClient) {}    

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    favoriteFood: [this.foods[0], [Validators.required]]
  });

  this.foods$ = of(this.foods);
  this.usuarios$ = this.getDataUsers();

}


httpClientService(url: string, params: any): Observable<Usuarios[]>{
  return this._http.get(url, params).pipe(
    map(
      (datas) => {
        let myTransformedDatas = [];
        for(let index in datas){
          myTransformedDatas.push(datas[index]);
        }
        return myTransformedDatas;
      }
    )
  );   
}

getDataUsers():Observable<Usuarios[]>{
  let urlGetUsuarios = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";   
  return this.httpClientService(urlGetUsuarios, {})
}

changeClient(datas){
    console.log("selected --->", datas);
    this.usuarios$.subscribe(data=>{
      console.log("array data",data[datas]);
    })
}
}
```